# A single word for a silent conversation/expression?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am branding my work and need a word to name my brand. I have words like silent, tacit and tête-a-tête.
But i am not completely convinced. I want to say self conversation/ silent expression.
I don't mind words in other languages or origin-etymology.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. If you're asking for a single-word meaning 'self-conversation', you might try soliloquy. 'Silent expression' is another kettle of fish...maybe 'mimicry'? Whatever, you should include a sentence with a blank where the word you want would fit, and add the tag 'single-word-request' if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I took the liberty to change all your tags, since you are clearly asking for a single word as per your (previous title). However it is mandatory to provide an example sentence to describe how the single word you are looking for will be used. Have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out about good answers.

Answer (score 0):

1.Imply

Eg.her expression implied that she is ready

2.Convey

Eg.he conveyed his regards to all the family members

3.Inform

Eg.the minister informed the defence authorities about the possibilities of a war

4.Express

Eg.she expressed her willingnes to travel as soon as she got the offer.

5.Signal

Eg.the innocent expression in her eyes signals something magical